# Image Sharing Using Google Plus in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, google-plus, socialshare

I want to share image on google plus:

I have used google+ api

AppDelegate.m

```
[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = @"MyClientID";
[GPPDeepLink setDelegate:self];
[GPPDeepLink readDeepLinkAfterInstall];
```

and on button action

ViewController.m

```
id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] shareDialog];

[shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dummy.com"]];
[shareBuilder setTitle:@"Some title" description:@"Some description" thumbnailURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dummy.com/image"]];
[shareBuilder setContentDeepLinkID:@"MyclientID"];
[shareBuilder open];
```

but on click it crashes ans error shows:

```
-[__NSDictionaryM gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e887ea0'
```

it crashes on [shareBuilder open]

Answer (score 38):

It is because you dont have set the **other linker Flag**,
Go to Build Setting and then
**Other Linker Flags: -ObjC**

Comment: Silly points we miss -- I had made the flag "-Objc".. changed it to "-ObjC" and it worked.

Comment: I have added google+ and facebook sign in both, now if i add -ObjC then facebook sdk starts giving errors, whats the middle way to support both

Answer (score 10):

open your build setting of target :

**build setting of target >goto linking section > Other linker flag** 
Set other linker flag to : **-ObjC**

make sure your character should be > -ObjC (matching case) .

Answer (score 1):

Amit Bhavsar say the correct. Go to Build Settings, Linking, set in Other Linker Flags, into debug and release, -ObjC. Check that you AppDelegate implement GPPDeepLinkDelegate and your views also.

Answer (score 1):

ObjC in other linker flags.
And if already add -ObjC try to remove it and again add it. For the 1st time i just copy past -ObjC and it was not working but after removing and again adding it starts working.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this issue, but finally i found the answer.
As above some of friends said, I forgot Add the ObjC linker flag to the app target's build settingss:

So, go to Build Settings page of Targets section of the app,
once gone over there, add following in Other Linker Flags

-ObjC

So, this may be helps you Friend!!!

Answer (score 0):

you are not assigning client_ id of GPPSignIn class. Try this code in your appdelegate

```
[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = @"MY_CLIENT_ID";
[GPPDeepLink setDelegate:self];
[GPPDeepLink readDeepLinkAfterInstall];
```

then try sharing [link for implementing it in right way](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share).

Comment: i assigned it in Appdelegate.m