# Facing issue with the google plus login IOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, google-signin

I am facing problem while integrating the google plus log
i got the following error:

```
2015-02-17 20:03:39.377 SIR[288:14344] -[__NSDictionaryM gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d57a20
2015-02-17 20:03:39.383 SIR[288:14344] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d57a20'
```

The code i used to google login is below:

```
 -(void) setGooglePlusButtons {
UIButton *googlePlusSignInButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] ;


UIImage *backgroundButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"google.png"];

googlePlusSignInButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                           400,
                                           150,
                                           50);

googlePlusSignInButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
googlePlusSignInButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11.0f];
googlePlusSignInButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

googlePlusSignInButton.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
googlePlusSignInButton.titleLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f,
                                                             -1.0f);

[googlePlusSignInButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"", @"")
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[googlePlusSignInButton setBackgroundImage:backgroundButtonImage
                                   forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:googlePlusSignInButton];

[googlePlusSignInButton addTarget:self action:@selector(signInGoogle) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];}

- (void)signInGoogle {
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.delegate = self;
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
signIn.clientID = KclientId;
signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin,nil];
signIn.actions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://schemas.google.com/ListenActivity",nil];
[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authenticate];}


- (void)signOut {
[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];}
```

and in app delegate

```
    - (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application openURL: (NSURL *)url sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation: (id)annotation {

return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];}
```

and i declared at the top kclientId

```
static NSString * const KclientId=@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
```

i have tried it on my end but i am not able to found the issue that where i am going wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image Sharing Using Google Plus in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857588/image-sharing-using-google-plus-in-ios)

Comment: @Larme i am getting this error while i am authenticate the GPPSignIn

Comment: for those guys who didn't find any solution after looking at below answers; please make sure you have added every necessary framework in project with target membership checked.

Answer (score 20):

I faced the same issue with Swift,I think you must enable some flags on the build setting and enable some library.

1. Go to Build settings / Linking / Other Linker Flags and add the "-ObjC" without the quotes. This assume you are using some "header file" to map Google framework and for Swift approach.
2. Go to Build Phases >Link Binary with Librairies > + > Add other, the go to de /usr/lib directory and select "libz.dylib"
3. Compile

Comment: It's not working for me, it's coming linker error. Anyone have solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The NSDictionary extension, that defines gtm_httpArgumentsString is located in GoogleToolboxForMac framework. Make sure you link to that framework.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add Google Utilities framework which was left.It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to add -ObjC flag, then you need to force load the framework it will work.

Add like this in your other linker flags
-force_load "path of your framework"

Let me know if you face any issue.